How properly migrate my selenide tests from selenoid to selenosis?
I have to move my tests to k8s. Previously, I run my tests in docker container with java and maven (dockerfile) against docker containers with browsers, like described in docker compose below with help of docker-compose. Could you please help me to understand what should I do to run my docker containers in k8s? Thank you a lot in advance for any help!
version: '3.8'

services:
  selenoid:
    image: aerokube/selenoid:latest-release
    container_name: selenoid
    network_mode: bridge
    ports:
      - ...
    volumes:
      - ...
    environment:
      - OVERRIDE_VIDEO_OUTPUT_DIR=/home/user/.aerokube/selenoid/video
      - USER_ID=${USER_ID}
    command: [ "-conf", "/etc/selenoid/browsers.json", "-limit", "4", "-video-output-dir", "/opt/selenoid/video", "-log-output-dir", "/opt/selenoid/logs" ]

  chrome_119:
    image: selenoid/chrome:125.0

  firefox_120:
    image: selenoid/firefox:120.0

  maven:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - selenoid
    volumes:
      - ...
    network_mode: host
    environment:
... //vars
    command: mvn clean test "${RUN_OPTIONS}"

